# Gap size calculation in time series with R

Tags: r, time-series

Let's say I have a dataframe with contains time series as below:

```
Date                value
2000-01-01 00:00:00  4.6
2000-01-01 01:00:00  N/A
2000-01-01 02:00:00  5.3
2000-01-01 03:00:00  6.0
2000-01-01 04:00:00  N/A
2000-01-01 05:00:00  N/A
2000-01-01 06:00:00  N/A
2000-01-01 07:00:00  6.0
```

I want to find an efficient way to calculate the size of the gap (number of consecutive N/As) and add it to a new column of my dataframe to get the following:

```
Date                value  gap_size
2000-01-01 00:00:00  4.6      0
2000-01-01 01:00:00  N/A      1
2000-01-01 02:00:00  5.3      0
2000-01-01 03:00:00  6.0      0
2000-01-01 04:00:00  N/A      3
2000-01-01 05:00:00  N/A      3
2000-01-01 06:00:00  N/A      3
2000-01-01 07:00:00  6.0      0
```

My dataframe in reality has more than 6 millions row so I am looking for the cheapest way in terms of computation. Note that my time series is equi-spaced over the whole dataset (1 hour).

Comment: what have you tried already?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far. The only thing I have in mind is looping through the dataframe, and I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `rle` in this case to generate run lengths. First, convert your value column to logical using `is.na` and apply `rle` which provides the run lengths of the different values of the input vector. In this case, the two categories are TRUE and FALSE, and you're counting how long they run for. You can then `rep`licate this by the run length to get the output you're looking for.

```
x = c(1,2,4,NA,NA,6,NA,19,NA,NA)
res = rle(is.na(x))
rep(res$values*res$lengths,res$lengths)
#> [1] 0 0 0 2 2 0 1 0 2 2
```

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set to `data.table` with setDT() and:

```
dt[, gap := rep(rle(value)$lengths, rle(value)$lengths) * (value == "N/A")]
                  Date value gap
1: 2000-01-01 00:00:00   4.6   0
2: 2000-01-01 01:00:00   N/A   1
3: 2000-01-01 02:00:00   5.3   0
4: 2000-01-01 03:00:00   6.0   0
5: 2000-01-01 04:00:00   N/A   3
6: 2000-01-01 05:00:00   N/A   3
7: 2000-01-01 06:00:00   N/A   3
8: 2000-01-01 07:00:00   6.0   0
```

Data:

```
dt <- structure(list(Date = c("2000-01-01 00:00:00", "2000-01-01 01:00:00", 
"2000-01-01 02:00:00", "2000-01-01 03:00:00", "2000-01-01 04:00:00", 
"2000-01-01 05:00:00", "2000-01-01 06:00:00", "2000-01-01 07:00:00"
), value = c("4.6", "N/A", "5.3", "6.0", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
"6.0")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: How could I adapt this code to work with multiple sites? For example, what if I had a time series for multiple sites and wanted to know what the largest gap was per site? @sindri_baldur

Comment: You could use the `by` argument.