# How to measure the average gap size in a time series panel per id?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, data.table, data-wrangling

In order to deal with product time series where lots of them showing intermittent demand, I want to measure how large the gaps consisting of zero values in between the series are.

In the next step I want to measure the average gap length per id. In my example this would be 4.33 for ID 1.

I found an older solution for measurement of gap sizes in time series, that does not give me the result in way, that I am able to process it further and derive measures like average gap size and min and max gap size:

[Gap size calculation in time series with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029171/gap-size-calculation-in-time-series-with-r)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

data <- tibble(id = as.factor(c(rep("1",24),rep("2",24),rep("3",24))),
               date = rep(c(ymd("2013-01-01")+ months(0:23)),3),
               value = c(c(rep(4,5),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,11,23,54,33,45,0),
                         c(4,6,1,2,3,4,4,6,8,11,18,6,6,1,7,7,13,9,4,33,3,6,81,45),
                         c(rep(4,5),0,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,7,0,0,8,0,11,23,54,33,0,0))
)


# this gives me the repeated gap size per observation
setDT(data)
data[, gap := rep(rle(value)$lengths, rle(value)$lengths) * (value == 0)]

# I want the distinct gap size per id 
1: c(8,4,1)
2: c(0)
3: c(3,3,2,1,2)
```

If I would be able to determine the number of gaps per id, I could also calculate the mean gap size, by retrieving the total number zeros per id like this (13/3 = 4.33):

```
# total number of zeros per id
data <- as_tibble(data)
data %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(zero_sum = length(which(value == 0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rle`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[,.(n=with(rle(value==0),lengths*values)),by=id][n>0]

       id     n
   <fctr> <int>
1:      1     8
2:      1     4
3:      1     1
4:      3     3
5:      3     3
6:      3     2
7:      3     1
8:      3     2
```

or in the expected format:

```
data[,.(n=list(with(rle(value==0),{r = lengths*values; 
                                   r <- r[r!=0];
                                   if (length(r)==0) {r <- 0L};
                                   r }))),by=id]

       id         n
   <fctr>    <list>
1:      1     8,4,1
2:      2         0
3:      3 3,3,2,1,2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is quite useful